# Count array elements returned by scandir(); PHP

Tags: php, count, scandir

I have in folder "files" some folders. I want to return the count of this folders by my php code:

```
$x = count(scandir('/files'));
echo $x;
```

But this is not working. What is wrong?

Comment: Whats the result of var_dump($x)?

Comment: Does apache user have reqired permission on "/files" folder?

Comment: *"this is not working"* means what? Errors? Wrong count? Empty output?

Answer (score 2):

If you have some files in **files** folder, Here is the solution.

```
  $directory = 'files/';
  $scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));//to remove dots
  $x = count($scanned_directory);
  echo $x;
```

Try not to use ***/files***. It will look for the file named **files**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$directory = '/your/directory/path/';
$files = glob($directory . '*.*');   // returns an array on success and false on error.

if ( $files !== false )
{
    $filecount = count( $files );
    echo $filecount;
}
else
{
    echo 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

its better to check if directory does even exist first :

```
$directory = '/your/directory/path/';
if(!is_dir($directory))
    die("direction not exists");
```

ant then count and remove `.` and `..` elements